# Looking for math software to play around with?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I am doing some research and I want to use software like Scilab or MATLAB to plug in values for a, for example, $2\times 2$ matrix and see how the linear combination of vectors' direction and magnitude are changed when different numbers (or eigenvalues, etc). are manipulated. However I tried scilab and it is extremely hard and I don't know how to write matrices in scilab. In fact, what is the best software to do this in?

I can quickly clarify any unclearances.

I FORGOT TO ADD I HAVE A MACBOOK.

Comment: In general, Maple (and probably Mathematica) are much easier to use than Matlab.  The big exception is matrices.  It is easier to define and manipulate matrices in Matlab, but it may be worth learning how to do it in Maple or Mathematica since just about everything else (such as plotting, derivatives, etc.) is so much harder in Matlab.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Why should I spend $140 when I can get what I need for free?

Comment: Have you tried SAGE?

Comment: @Don Larynx : I don't know much about you, including whether you have free access to Maple and/or Mathematica, which many participants in MSE do.  When you say "get what you need", keep in mind the adage "you get what you pay for".  Octave is free but its creators have a weird command-line fetish, and as a result it is at least difficult to find and install a good IDE like Matlab has.  I have heard great things about SAGE.  I installed it once, and I found it tricky to install and use, and I found it harder to use than Maple.  It may have changed since then.

Comment: @StefanSmith: I shall buy Mathematica if you show me a beginner guide to it.

Comment: @DonLarynx : Since I have free access to Maple, I have not bothered with Sage since.  Your question did not specifically say what software you already had, not did you mention you were looking for free software.  You may get better answers if you put this information in your question.

Comment: @DonLarynx : my two cents: IMHO, Maple syntax is more natural and easier to learn than Mathematica syntax.  In Maple, you just type what you want.  Mathematica syntax has weird stuff like insisting on capital letters for command names and square braces, plus you have to type shift-enter to execute a command, not just enter (unlike every other programming language I've heard of).  Many people prefer Mathematica and will give counterarguments.  Either Maple or Mathematica will probably do everything you need.  There are probably tons of beginner's guides to both freely available...

Comment: ???? @StefanSmith

Comment: @DonLarynx : a good place to ask "Where can I find a good intro guide to Mathematica" is probably Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DonLarynx : regarding Octave, I have heard that Octave can't really do symbolic computations at all.  If this is important to you, you should check whether this is really the case before you try Octave.  Matlab can do symbolic computations but not gracefully.  With Maple or Mathematica, or course, symbolic computations are as easy or easier than numerical ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you really could learn a lot from Mathematica, language is pretty simple and very connected to algebraic manipulations, also with very few knowledge of the language (even plain and simple English) you can do most of the computational stuff from calculus, linear algebra, complex analysis and discrete mathematics.

Comment: Why should I pay $140 when I can get Octave, R, etc. for free?

Comment: Where is a guide

Comment: I use a licence from my university, I know that most colleges in the states have an agreement with wolfram, so usually for students enrolled at an university institution Mathematica is free, for a guide, I would recommend "programming with mathematica an introduction" from paul wellin.

Also, you can find waldo with mathematica see: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Octave, its syntax is very similar to MATLAB and it is free.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend R. It is free, and very nice to do a lot of things with. Especially R Studio is recommended to use, the interface is one of the better ones I think.